# React-Native: Screen gets cut in half

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I've encountered the following bug with react-native:

As soon as I rotate my smartphone and then turn it back to normal, my screen gets cut in half, the lower half of my scrollview is now completely white. This also happens when I call react-native-modal and dismiss it.

Does any know how to handle this?

Comment: You also have the option to have it Portrait only

Comment: Seems to be a good quick fix! Even though I still wonder why it's behaving like this

Comment: Honestly i also dont know why, maybe lets just wait for someone who have encountered that issue.

Comment: @NicoleW. just check my answer please

Comment: @JovylleBermudez yours also solves the problem partially, but if you want landscape you can deal with like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic scenario of how you have built your components on every screen of app.This may occur even if you test it out in different phones, like phones which have large screen height / width.
If you use dynamic width and height or every component, your app would look the same in both portrait and landscape mode.

Suppose you set a `<View style={{height:50}} />` , and now 50 in every phone and in landscape mode is different. suppose you a screen resolution of 360(w)*640(h) . Now when you landscape it, it just reverses. now height is just 360(h).  So it may happen your screen gets cut.

I would suggest get device height and width:

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
```

Now suppose you want to have a view of height 50, and that's 50 or your phone looks good nad you know your phone height is 640, so simple you can calculate `50/640= 0.078` . SO now you can create a dynamic View with like this :

```
<View style={{height:0.078*windowHeight}} />
```

Now in every screen it will make a responsive design

hope it helps. feel free for doubt

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help, the screen still gets cut in half!

Comment: I now found the problem, it was the Swiper-View lying over the ScrollView.. you're comment made me look for height of every element in the hierarchy, so you helped me out a lot! Thank you!

Comment: @NicoleW. glad it helped. you can upvote and mark as accepted if you think it was helpful. thanks :)